# Caret stops blinking event in TextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am looking for an event that will fire when the caret of a `TextBox` stops blinking. Lets say I have:

```
<TextBox LostFocus="txtBox_LostFocus" />
```

In order for the event `txtBox_LostFocus` to be fired another control has to receive focus meanwhile that control has focus. **If I click on the textbox the | starts blinking. When I click outside the textbox the | stops blinking and the LostFocus event doesn't get called why?** The LostFocus event only gets called if I click on another focusable control. How can I know when the | stops blinking?

Note I call the | a cursor perhaps it has a different name.

### **Also**

I used the `Keyboard.ClearFocus();` when the user presses ENTER on the textbox to stop the Caret from blinking. This also raises the `LostKeyboardFocus` event!

Comment: it's called ***caret***.

Comment: I've also called it a caret, I think text cursor is also fine though =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to test it just at this second, but looking at the available events for the `TextBox` class on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) there is a [`LostKeyboardFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostkeyboardfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event that sounds like it might be what you're after.

> LostKeyboardFocus - Occurs when the keyboard is no longer focused on
>   this element. (Inherited from UIElement.)

Comment: +1 exactly what I needed thanks so much! I accept this answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me. Thanks again

Comment: Glad that was the one, I had a memory of using it once, but couldn't be certain without testing =D